# Связать контролы

Tags: c#

Есть 20 кнопок и 20 чекбоксов. Задача сделать кнопку активной по нажатию чекбокса. Можно ли это сделать проще, чем создав два массива проставить одинаковые индексы.

Comment: WPF или WinForms? Или может быть, Silverlight? ASP? В кадом из фреймворков своя техника.

А вообще-то, может быть, вам просто нужен цикл `for`?

Comment: WinForms. Как в цикле for составить название контрола?
buttoni, где i переменная цикла

Comment: А зачем вам название, простите? Вы, надеюсь, генерируете все 20 пар контролов тоже циклом, а не вручную?

Comment: Нет, они у меня статично размещены на форме.

Comment: @demmy: Ну так вот это и неправильно. Если у вас 20 контролов, генерируйте их циклом, а не повторением одного и того же кода 20 раз подряд. Вы же не индус?

Comment: @VladD справедливости ради много раз писать одно и то же - это не индусский, это китайский код (не знаю, почему китайский, может вообще просто так). Индусский - это более круто)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно каждому чекбоксу в свойство `Tag` засунуть ссылку на соответствующую ему кнопку. Затем подписать все чекбоксы на один обработчик нажатия, в котором написать нечто подобное:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
Button button = checkBox.Tag as Button;
if (button != null)
{
    button.Enabled = checkBox.Checked;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В Tag чекбоксов - номер.

```
cb.CheckedChanged += (s,e) => {
    Button btn = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().FindByName("button" + cb.Tag.ToString()).Single();
    btn.Enabled = (sender as CheckBox).Checked;
}
```